# What is the Ubuntu Server GUI wifi setup package?

Tags: wireless

I somehow get so much trouble setting up the internet. I am trying to install the Wifi package that let me set it up on a GUI configuration. I used it before but I cannot find it right now.

Comment: Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI.

Comment: Maybe you used raspi-config to setup the wifi on a raspberry pi, and are misremembering using that on an Ubuntu server?

Comment: I was using `nmtui` this. Maybe I chose the wrong word `GUI`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no GUI and the command is `nmcli` and that is part of networkmanager package. The commands are ...

To list the available wifi interface(s):

```
nmcli d
```

To turn wifi on:

```
nmcli r wifi on
```

To list available wifi networks:

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

To connect:

```
nmcli d wifi connect {ssid} password {password}
```

---

In case it is a hidden network:

One time:

```
nmcli c add type wifi con-name {connectionname} ifname wlan0 ssid {ssid}
nmcli c modify {connectionname} wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk {password}
```

And then to connect:

```
nmcli c up {connectionname}
```

Comment: hmm i see. I remember I did something like not GUI but it was very easy. But, thank you! I will do that now.

Answer (score 3):

there is tool called `nmtui` that looks like this

https://scr.vodolaz095.ru/s/2e0dGvtWa.png

you can install it using command `sudo apt-get install nmtui`

Comment: It was something like this. But in English?

Comment: yes, this tool has localization set accordint to `localectl`